# Data for unlisted videos

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

Currently, we have a video that is unlisted on youtube, but embedded in our website with a link so that visitors on the site can view. but it won't show up on youtube search. I am trying to retrieve views data for this video through the youtube analytics api, but I am unable to find it. Does youtube restrict metrics from unlisted videos through their API?

Comment: Why not just using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part)`=`[`statistics`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics) to retrieve [`statistics.viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount)?